# how to get text from edit text which is in scroll view?

Tags: android

Hi am adding edit text field dynamically to the scroll view and then am adding a text into the edit text and then i want to get back data into string array...for that i wrote a following code please suggest me how to get the data from edit text..`for(int i=0;i

```
            value=(EditText)row.findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
            Button sayit=(Button)row.findViewById(R.id.sayit);
            Button sentence=(Button)row.findViewById(R.id.sentences);   
            TextView positions=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.positions);
            TextView sentenc=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.sentence);

            positions.setText(String.valueOf(i));
            sentenc.setText(String.valueOf(i));



            sayit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    {
                        TextView t=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.positions);
                        String s=t.getText().toString();
                        int j=Integer.parseInt(s);
                        mTts.speak(field_wordsundvalue[j],TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
                    }
            });
            sentence.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    {
                        TextView t1=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.sentence);
                        String s=t1.getText().toString();
                        int j=Integer.parseInt(s);
                        mTts.speak(field_sentencesundvalue[j],TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
                    }
            });             
        ll.addView(row);
        mylist.add(value);  
        }`
```

Comment: Please look at your code snippet. It does not include all the needed code (e.g. declarations). Also please improve the formatting.

Comment: am getting those edittexts dynamically by using parsing data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code is use to get the text from edit Text,

```
String str = myEditText.getText().toString().trim();
```

Comment: after adding the above line into the code i get only the current value  but i want to get all the edittext values into array

Comment: @Santosh did you found a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
value.getText().toString()
```

Comment: after adding the above line into the code i get only the current value  but i want to get all the edittext values into array